# firefox svg not working with session values

Tags: firefox, svg, sessionstorage

My svg works in google chrome and IE,( microsoft edge ).

The problem is firefox assigns the default value 0 to x1.  x1 value has been set as 20 to start and is increased by 20 each iteration by stored sessions.

My code is:

```
for ($k=0; $k<$n;$k++)

{


?>


 <line x1 = "<? echo $XLP[$k];  ?>" , y1 = "<?    echo $YAB[$k];  ?>" x2 =  "<?   echo "   ", $XLP[$k+1];  ?>"  , y2 =  "<?    echo $YAB[$k+1];  ?>"  style="fill:none; stroke:rgb(0,80,255);stroke-width:3" />    


<?

}
```

Comment: Delete the commas between the attributes of the `<line>` element, they are not valid markup.

Comment: deleting the commas does not work.  The issue is can firefox SVG handle SESSION stored values.